# How can I close a NSWindow loaded modally as popup, by clicking outside of it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I close a NSWindow loaded modally as popup, by clicking outside of it?

I would like to handle the mouse event, when the cursor is outside the modal window with the focus (but still inside the app).

Answer (score 0):

You may implement the following delegate method of `NSWindow` to get the notification of window losing focus.

```
- (void)windowDidResignKey:(NSNotification *)notification
```

And inside check, if your application is the front most App. If yes then close accordingly.

Comment: This method invoked *after* the window is dismissed, which is what I want to achieve, and not before.

Comment: This is because you are using a modal window and modal window doesnt lose focus until it is closed, you may try using NSFloatingWindowLevel instead to get similar functionality

Comment: Also have a look at http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/310559-how-to-detect-clicks-outside-of-modal-window.html and try if the last answer by David Riggle works. I havent tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

> While the application is in modal run loop, it does not respond to any
>   other events (including mouse, keyboard, or window-close events)
>   unless they are associated with the window. It also does not perform
>   any tasks (such as firing timers) that are not associated with the
>   modal run loop.

You can use `nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:` method.This will work in modal loop.

> Both NSWindow and NSApplication define the method
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:, which allows an
>   object to retrieve events of specific types from the event queue.

Comment: However, *(NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint* is actually called in the object below my window. But it seems to be invoked many times even when I don't click it, it doesn't seem very reliable method to me, to place my code there.

Comment: use nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above it is necessary to override [NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] method. In my case (plugin) I have to use the existing instance of a 3rd party unknown class derived from NSApplication. I can't just derive a new class from it. Thus I use `method_exchangeImplementations` to exchange the named method above with my own implementation

```
+ (void)hijack
{
    Class appClass = [NSApplication class];
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(appClass, @selector(nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:));
    Method categoryMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(appClass, @selector(my_nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, categoryMethod);
}
```

which looks as follows:

```
- (NSEvent *)my_nextEventMatchingMask:(NSUInteger)mask untilDate:(NSDate *)expiration inMode:(NSString *)mode dequeue:(BOOL)deqFlag
{
    NSEvent *event = [self my_nextEventMatchingMask:mask untilDate:expiration inMode:mode dequeue:deqFlag];

    NSEventType type = [event type]; // 0 if event is nil
    if (type == NSLeftMouseDown || type == NSRightMouseDown)
    {
        if ([self modalWindow] != nil && [event window] != [self modalWindow])
        {
            [self stopModalWithCode:NSModalResponseCancel];
            event = nil;
        }
    }
    return event;
}
```

And finally the modal window is invoked as follows:

```
[NSApplication hijack];
[NSApp runModalForWindow:window];
[NSApplication hijack];
```

Obviously if you can just override NSApplication then you don't need to define and call `hijack` method.